# CSS dashed drop shadow

Tags: pseudo-element, css

Let's say I have a span with a dashed underline:

```
<span class="underline">Hello, I'm underlined text</span>

.underline {
  color: #444;
  font-size: 250%;
  display:inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #444;
}
```

I need a bottom drop shadow for the underline. I assume box-shadow is not the case and the only possible solution is to do it by the means of pseudo elements.
I'm doing this way:

```
.underline:after {
  content:"";
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #ff0000;
  display: block;
 }
```

This displays the red dashed stroke *above* the underline but I need to do that below the underline. 
How is that possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `position: relative;` like this:

```
.underline:after {
  content:"";
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #ff0000;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you don't want to use box-shadow (unless its a browser problem) But it would solve the problem.

```
box-shadow: 0px 10px #888888;

.underline {
  color: #444;
  font-size: 250%;    
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px #888888;
  display:inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #444;
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: Because I need a drop shadow for the underline, not the solid shadow for the entire box. See me above.